# CheckBox does not change the value when I try to validate it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I try to validate state of checkbox but I'm not sure does my syntax is OK?!
In view I have this:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {

        <table>
            @for (var i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
            {
                var curItem = items[i];
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.CheckBox("chk" + i.ToString(), false)
                        @curItem.Text
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    }

        <a href="~/Welcome/GoNext" class="btn btn-success" role="button" style="width:130px; height:30px">Start</a>
```

and in my controller I have GoNext action method:

```
public ActionResult GoNext()
{

    bool isOption0Checked = Request["chk0"] != null ? Request["chk0"].ToString() == "true" : false;
    bool isOption1Checked = Request["chk1"] != null ? Request["chk1"].ToString() == "true" : false;
    bool isOption2Checked = Request["chk2"] != null ? Request["chk2"].ToString() == "true" : false;


    if (isOption0Checked && isOption1Checked && isOption2Checked)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index","Tab1");
    }
    else
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(String.Empty, "Message");

        return Index();

    }
```

So, when I check my checkbox it does not change the value from false to true (it allways remaining false)?! I have doubt about this syntax:

```
bool isOption0Checked = Request["chk0"] != null ? Request["chk0"].ToString() == "true" : false;
```

It is correct like this?!

Comment: I would create a view model for your view to bind to. Then add action and controller attributes to your form to post the values back to your controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are total in right!! I did not notice that the button is outside of the form and also the method is GET. When I made this changes and also the syntax that I had doubt above everything work fine. But I find the most elegant solution like this:
I define one model:

```
  public class WelcomeModel {
  public bool chk0 {get;set;}
  public bool chk1 { get; set; }
  public bool chk2 { get; set; }

  }
```

and now my GoNext action look like this:

```
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult GoNext()
  {
  WelcomeModel CheckState = new WelcomeModel();
  TryUpdateModel(CheckState );
  if (CheckState.chk0 && CheckState.chk1 && CheckState.chk2 != false)
  {
  return RedirectToAction("Index", "Tab1");
  }

  else
  {
  ModelState.AddModelError(String.Empty, "Message");

  return Index();

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have a few problems there:

1. your button (in your case ) is an outside of form.
2. your
   button sends 'GET' request (not 'POST'), therefore the values of
   your checkboxes weren't sent to server.
3. the check that you use
   returns false not because of value in `false`
   (Request["chk0"].ToString() 1= "true"), but because of value doesn't
   exist at all (Request["chk0"] == null).

The simplest solution: modify your form declaring like `@using (Html.BeginForm(("GoNext", "Welcome", FormMethod.Post))` (if I'm not mistaken in syntax)

You can also put the custom button inside your form in order if you want to have a custom submit button.

Hope that will help.